# Xcode - How can I view all the methods inside the current class I am looking at?

Tags: xcode

It just struck me! How can I get a list of all the methods inside the class I'm currently looking at? Realized scrolling up and down or Find isn't the best way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i guess using the xcode jump bar would be the best...

[Jump Bar Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-jump_bar/Recipe.html)